# How to use a vector of shared pointers to ojbects

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to use a vector of shared pointers to objects.  I don't have any trouble getting any of the member variables but nothing seems to work when I try setting member variables.  I must be missing something here because this seems like it should be working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

    class vehicle{

        public:
            vehicle(){};
            ~vehicle(){};

            virtual string getName(){
                return this->name;
            }

            virtual string setName(string n){
               this->name = n;
           }

            friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outs, vehicle &v){
            outs << v.getName();
            return outs;
            }

       protected:
           string name;

    };

    class car : public vehicle{

        public:

            car(){
                this->name = "default name";
            }

            string setName(string n){
                this->name = n;
            }

            string getName(){
                return this->name;
            }
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<vehicle> vehicle_ptr;
```

cout will print the string "default name" and then when I try to change the name
it will cause a seg fault.

```
int main(){
       std::vector<vehicle_ptr> vehicleLot;

       vehicleLot.push_back(std::shared_ptr<car>(new car));

       cout << vehicleLot[0]->getName() << endl;

       vehicleLot[0]->setName("new name"); // this gives a seg fault

}
```

Comment: Use [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) instead of `new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `setName` method currently has a return type of `std::string` rather than `void`. Fix the signature in both your `vehicle` and `car` classes.

Reaching the end of a function that expects a return type without a return statement is undefined behavior. It would be a good idea to turn on the appropriate warnings for your compiler of choice, as this is easily caught by most compilers.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Which warnings would I use?

Comment: Consider compiling with -Wall enabled if you are using gcc. To enable this specific warning use -Wreturn-type

Comment: That works. -Wall shows it as a return type error so I'll leave that on now.

Answer (score 3):

The bug in your code is caused by the wrong definition of your `setName` function. Have a look what it returns :

```
virtual string setName(string n);
```

However, you're not explicitly returning anything, which I believe leads to undefined behaviour.

On a side note, you should use `const&` much more often in this code.

Comment: Can you explain or point me to more about where I need to use const&?

Comment: @JDD : because it saves you unneeded copy constructor calls. In your current way of passing/returning `string` objects, you pass and return them as `string`, which means that you pass/return a copy of the original object every time. By stating the return value/parameter as `const string&`, you tell the compiler that a copy is not needed, because you're not going to modify the original variable, and you don't need a copy of it, just a reference.